# node.js overwritte params Object

Tags: xml, node.js

I'm starting with Node.js and I have the following problem:
I have an XM fileL to parse with different nodes and I want to extract the information and put in an `Array` to pass to into a form:

```
var nodes = xpath.select("//return_address", doc)

var addresses = [];

for (i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){ 
    var node =nodes[i];
    var address = {
        code:   xpath.select1("//return_address/@code", node),
        house_no:       xpath.select1("//return_address/@house_no", node),
        postcode:      xpath.select1("//return_address/@postcode", node)
              };

    addresses.push(address);
}

//exit:
for (i=0;i<addresses.length;i++){ 
    console.log("addresses.code "+addresses[i].code.value); 
    console.log("         .house_no:    "+addresses[i].house_no.value); 
    console.log("         .postcode:    "+addresses[i].postcode.value); 
}
```

and this is the result when: `addresses.length = 3`

```
addresses.ptc_abs_code 58150004026

     .house_no:    27

     .postcode:    BA133BN

addresses.ptc_abs_code 58150004026

     .house_no:    27

     .postcode:    BA133BN

addresses.ptc_abs_code 58150004026

     .house_no:    27


     .postcode:    BA133BN
```

I have three different node, but it always prints out the last one, why is this happening?

Answer (score -1):

You need to put var before i = 0

```
for (var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++)
```

Luckily Node.js is not as permitive as browser is.